# perform a replacement with awk and sed from a file pattern to a file

Tags: text-processing

I have this `file_1` which have 3 columns separeted by tab or space.

```
Hhhg_2345_4567_33678    Hhhg_2345_4567_33678    97.0376
Hhhg_2345_4567_33679    Tyre_56576_567_899  70.4077
Hhhg_2345_4567_33680    Jyu_679__89090  79.0189
Hhhg_2345_4567_33681    abc_tyhiulo_89098   97.139
Hhhg_2345_4567_33682    gui_tyu_5678_4567   70.3177
Tyre_56576_567_899  abc_tyhiulo_89098   70.3442
Tyre_56576_567_900  Hhhg_2345_4567_33678    70.4117
Tyre_56576_567_901  Jyu_679__89090  99.9985
```

And I have this second file (`file_2`) which are my patterns, separated by space or tab

```
Hhhg_2345_4567_33678    EC
Tyre_56576_567_899  CI
Jyu_679__89090  SA
```

What I want to do, is to create a command to replace the strings which are in the `file_2` to the strings which are in the `file_1`. So the output should look like:

```
EC  EC  97.0376
EC  CI  70.4077
EC  SA  79.0189
EC  abc_tyhiulo_89098   97.139
EC  gui_tyu_5678_4567   70.3177
CI  abc_tyhiulo_89098   70.3442
CI  Hhhg_2345_4567_33678    70.4117
```

I tried with this:

```
sed '/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/{H;d;};G;s/ \([^ ]*\)\n.*\n\1 \([[:print:]]*\).*/ \1   \2/;P;d' file2 file1
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Your input and output aren't consistent with your description of the problem.  The `EC` pattern matches only in the first and seventh lines, but your expected output shows it matching much more often than that.

Comment: Duplicate with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673816/replace-multiple-strings-from-a-file-to-another-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace multiple strings from a file to another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673816/replace-multiple-strings-from-a-file-to-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk program.

File: `pattern.awk`

```c
# Store "file 2" (the first on command line)
NR == FNR {
    h[$1] = $2
    next
}
# Check "file 1" (the second on command line)
h[$1] != "" {
    $1 = h[$1]
}
h[$2] != "" {
    $2 = h[$2]
}
{
    print
}
```

With this command line (warning, file order is VERY important):

```bsh
awk -f pattern.awk file2 file1
```

The output will be:

```
EC EC 97.0376
Hhhg_2345_4567_33679 CI 70.4077
Hhhg_2345_4567_33680 SA 79.0189
Hhhg_2345_4567_33681    abc_tyhiulo_89098   97.139
Hhhg_2345_4567_33682    gui_tyu_5678_4567   70.3177
CI abc_tyhiulo_89098 70.3442
Tyre_56576_567_900 EC 70.4117
Tyre_56576_567_901 SA 99.9985
```

(not exactly your desired output, see Jim L. comment)

Comment: thank you very  @ArnaudValmary much, it worked perfectly, but (i do not know why) the output file has ^M character between the columns, and when I open the file with notepad, the rows turns to one column

Comment: @user:489056 thank you very much, it worked perfectly, but My output file has the ^M character between the columns and when I open the archive , the rows turn to one column

Comment: @JulianaBC If your input file or the script file have been edited using Windows-based text editors, you may have to run `dos2unix` over the respective file, as Windows and Linux have different line-ending indicators.

Comment: @JulianaBC, sorry, I'm almost exclusively working under UNIX or UNIX-like systems. You could call `awk -f pattern.awk <(cat file2 | dos2unix) <(cat file1 | dos2unix)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a suitable job for a macro processor `m4`.

> Macro names - *A name is any sequence of letters, digits, and the character `_` (underscore), where the first character is not a digit.*

```
m4 <<\EOF
patsubst(include(`file_2'), `\(\S+\)\s+\(\S+\)', `define(`\1', `\2')dnl')dnl
include(`file_1')dnl
EOF
```

Output:

```
EC    EC    97.0376
Hhhg_2345_4567_33679    CI  70.4077
Hhhg_2345_4567_33680    SA  79.0189
Hhhg_2345_4567_33681    abc_tyhiulo_89098   97.139
Hhhg_2345_4567_33682    gui_tyu_5678_4567   70.3177
CI  abc_tyhiulo_89098   70.3442
Tyre_56576_567_900  EC    70.4117
Tyre_56576_567_901  SA  99.9985
```

But if you need a partial match in the pattern that excludes the last digits, then it is better to use GNU AWK:

```
awk '
NR==FNR && sub(/[0-9]+$/,"", $1) \
    {A[$1] = $2; next}
    {for(i in A) gsub(i"[0-9]+", A[i])}
1' file_2 file_1
```

Output:

```
EC    EC    97.0376
EC    CI  70.4077
EC    SA  79.0189
EC    abc_tyhiulo_89098   97.139
EC    gui_tyu_5678_4567   70.3177
CI  abc_tyhiulo_89098   70.3442
CI  EC    70.4117
CI  SA  99.9985
```